# Proof of solvability of Galois group of Solvable extension.

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, solvable-groups

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why we can assume that $F$ contains any primitive m roots of unity.

Does it have anything to do with [If $F \subset L$ is a radical extension, is $F(c_1,c_2,...,c_n)\subset L(c_1,c_2,...,c_n)$ radical?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982401/if-f-subset-l-is-a-radical-extension-is-fc-1-c-2-c-n-subset-lc-1-c-2).

In that case are we actually trying to prove the solvability of  $F(c_1,c_2,...,c_n)\subset L(c_1,c_2,...,c_n)$?

Pls see following link(I tired to prove without the assumption.):
[Galois group of Solvable extension is solvable. (Proof)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982587/galois-group-of-solvable-extension-is-solvable-proof)

Comment: @J. Darné Could you have a look at this too? Thanks. Been stuck for quite some time.